# Static website css and js works fine on local (PC) but not on hosting

Tags: css, hosting, cpanel

I have a static website that I want to post on a cPanel hosting. All the pages load perfectly fine on my PC, but when uploaded on the cPanel hosting, the CSS isn't loading.

The location of the css folder is as it is on the PC.

`<link id="color-link" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css">`

The domain's root was pointed to the directory where the `index.html` file is, and all the directory for the project is kept the same it was on PC.

Comment: The success of that relative link to the CSS file is very dependent on the location of the file it appears in. If that's how the link appears on your home page, you're pointing to the `assets` folder that's *next* to your home folder (that is, outside `public_html`). A better approach is to use "root-relative" URLs, which will work from any page at any level.

Comment: The `../` at the start of the link means to go up one level in the directory tree. This relative link works if you have for example `project/pages/index.html` and `project/assets/css/style.css`.  If "pages" is the root directory, then relative link to `../assets` is broken. [A quick primer on URLs and paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#a_quick_primer_on_urls_and_paths)

Answer (score 0):

The `link` element's `href` property shows that the stylesheet is not located in the same directory (or a subdirectory) as `index.html`. This will not work with most servers, including Apache (you're using cPanel, which typically runs Apache).

---

Let's say you have the following directory structure:

```
Web project
 |-- assets
 |     |-- style.css
 |
 |-- site
       |-- subdirectory
       |     |-- image.jpg
       |
       |-- index.html
       |-- favicon.ico
```

and your domain points to `site` (the root directory), where `index.html` is.

We could access the file `index.html` by requesting `http://example.com/index.html`. Similarly, we could access the favicon by going to `http://example.com/favicon.ico`. And we could also acces files in subdirectories - in the example above we could access `http://example.com/subdirectory/image.jpg`

However, we can't access the `assets` directory from the domain. The server's root directory is `site directory` - that is, it's has been configured to point the domain there - and it will refuse to process files outside of that directory. Since `assets directory` is not a descendant of `site directory`, no files from that directory can be served. If the server receives a request for `http://example.com/../assets/style.css` it will return an error.

This is not unique to cPanel or Apache. Virtually no general use webserver will process requests made outside of the root directory.

---

The simplest solution would be to move the `assets` directory to be inside the `site` directory, and then update all references accordingly.

```
Web project
 |-- site
       |-- assets
       |     |-- style.css
       |
       |-- index.html
       |-- favicon.ico
```

```html
<link id="color-link" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

Note, however, if you have any other references to `assets` - for example image URLs - you'll also have to update them.